# Google Apps Script - Set a fixed length of digit for making an auto-increment ID numbers in Google Sheets on every Form submission

Tags: google-apps-script

**Google Apps Script** - 
Please help me, I am having trouble with Google Apps Script.
I was making an order entry ID in Google Sheets but to create a neat ID with uniform length of digits, I figured I need to repeat a string of **'0'** a number of times before an **auto increment number** in google sheets (set a fixed length of digits for the ID like **1,2...5...10** would be **0001,0002...0005...0010**)

So far I have the auto-incrementing number function working fine already, it is just the repeating '0' function that doesn't

This is the code:

```
function onFormSubmit(e)
{
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var row =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();

   var tally = sheet.getRange("AG2").getValue();
   tally++;

   sheet.getRange(row,2).setValue(tally);
   sheet.getRange("AG2").setValue(tally);
*\\above is the code for the auto incrementing ID numbers*  

   if (tally.length<4) 
   {
     sheet.getRange(row,2).setValue('0'.repeat(4-tally.length), tally);
   }
*\\this is supposedly the code for setting up a fixed length of 4 digits for 
the ID but i was assuming that a javascript's: 'string'.repeat should work on 
google script.*
}
```

This, however, doesn't work so the output is still an incrementing ID number for every form submitted but the digits length is not fixed to 4 digits so I was getting **1,2,3...10,11** instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pad a value with leading zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-pad-a-value-with-leading-zeros)

Comment: @tehhowch This may be a partial duplicate but I think the reason the person is getting the wrong result is formatting in Google Sheets. Calling setValue("0001") on a cell will output 1, but if you prefix the number with an apostrophe as in setValue(" '0001 "), the number will be converted to text with the leading zeros preserved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the example that might help you. Don't forget to prefix the leading zero with **'** as it will prevent the sheet from formatting your output as a number. Otherwise, it'll just ignore the leading zeros.

```
      var zeros = "00000000000000000000000";      
      var values = [];          
      for (var i= 0; i < maxValues; i++) {

        values.push(["'" + zeros.substring(-1, 4 - i.toString().length) + i]);

      }

      var range = sheet.getRange(startRow, startColumn, values.length, 1);
      range.setValues(values);  

    }
```

**Update**
Google Apps Script is based on the ECMAScript standard that doesn't support String.prototype.repeat() unfortunately.